# Add mean and standard error bar for each seperate graph + change shape dots per trial

Tags: ggplot2

I am making a graph for my research results in Rstudio with ggplot. I want to make a dotplot with mean + standard error for each trial, however when I try to add the mean with stat_summary, the mean is taken from two different trials (yellow and blue). How can I make it for each different trial?

Also, I want to change the colour of the dots from the different trials to different shapes of the dots for each trial (all black). How do I do this?

```
ggdotplot(Plot1, x="Dose", y="Y", fill="Trial", color = "Trial",
       palette= "jco",
       ylab = "#",
       ylim = c(0,10),
       legend="none") + 
  facet_grid("Age") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "pointrange") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size=1))
```

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - You need to specify the `group` aesthetic and set a `position=` to draw separate pointranges in the correct position.

The way in which the data is split by "Trial" for each value of "Dose" in your plot is referred to as **dodging**.  In the case of the dotplot geom, when you specify the color or fill aesthetic, this forces `ggplot2` to draw dots of multiple colors... they are thus grouped accordingly and it is inferred that they should be "dodged" (separated along a subdivision of the x axis).  In the call to draw the pointrange geom, there is no aesthetic specified that would result in telling `ggplot2` *"Hey, you need to draw more than one of these for each x."*  Therefore, `ggplot2` uses the default aesthetics of `x` and `y` only - resulting in one pointrange geom for every x value.

Here's an example like the OP's question built from the `iris` dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# setting up an example dataset
set.seed(12345)
df <- iris
df$subdiv <- sample(c("A", "B"), size=nrow(df), replace=TRUE)

p <- ggdotplot(df, x="Species", y="Sepal.Length", fill="subdiv")
p + stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom="pointrange")
```

[image]

To force the data to be grouped and have a specific pointrange geom drawn for each unique pairing of "Dose" and "Trial", you need to also specify the `group=` aesthetic in the call to the pointrange geom.

When we specify the `group=` aesthetic, it works fine to draw more than one geom.  Without specifying anything further, they will still be drawn according to the default value for `position=`, which is "identity".  To get them to be drawn with dodging, you will need to specify this.  I had to play with the value for `width=` to get the right amount of dodging, since I'm not sure the value used within the wrapper function, `ggdotplot()`.

```
p+stat_summary(
    fun.data = mean_sdl, geom="pointrange",
    aes(group=subdiv),                       # set group aesthetic to separate by "subdiv"
    position=position_dodge(width = 0.8))    # Manually specify width with some trial & error
```

[image]